# Problemas com plugin Ionic Native Device Accounts

Tags: ionic, typescript, ionic3

Estou tentando obter as contas cadastradas no dispositivo com o plugin device accounts do ionic, porém na promise não tem me retornado nada no console.

O meu código é :

```
  testeSemNative() {
    DeviceAccounts.getPlugin().getEmail(
     account => console.log('Account' + account),
      error => console.error(error));

    DeviceAccounts.getPlugin().get(
     accounts => console.dir(accounts),
      error => console.error(error));
   }

   testeComNative() {
     this.deviceAccounts.get()
       .then(accounts => console.log(accounts))
       .catch(error => console.error(error));
   }
```

Pesquisei em alguns lugares, e tinha um tópico sugerindo para usar um outro modelo de código, portanto tentei realizar um teste utilizando o ionic native, e outro teste chamando diretamente o plugin, porém em ambos não consegui obter nenhum resultado

Comment: Você está testando no emulador, ou gerou a .pk e instalou no celular?

Comment: Estou testando diretamente no celular, testei em pelo menos 3 dispositivos e não obtive sucesso.

Comment: Você já utilizou o plugin? Ou sabe de algum outro que eu possa obter o mesmo resultado?